# When adding a product via api what are all the possible variable? api is only showing examples

Tags: shopify

Does anyone have a link or an example of all the possibile variables when adding a product via api. Or perhaps it's better said accepted key=value pairs.

The docs api has weak examples of this and that, but no definitive array that shows all accepted args.

http://api.shopify.com/product.html#create

Here is what I've *sort of* pieced together from the api examples and trial and error.

```
$array = array(
        'id' => $item->store_id,
        'title' => $this->sanitize( $item->name ),
        'body_html' => $this->sanitize( $item->romance_copy ),
        'vendor' => $item->brand,
        'product_type' => $item->ware_desc, // may not be correct
        'tags' => $item->keyword,
        'images' => array(),
        'metafields' => array(),
        // http://wiki.shopify.com/Variant#variant.id
        'variants' => array( // Single variant is required for each product.
            array( 
                'id' => $item->store_id,
                'option1' => 'First',
                'price' => $item->price_msrp,
                // 'compare_at_price' => '',
                // 'available' => '',
                'inventory_quantity' => $item->inventory_quantity,
                // 'weight' => '',
                'sku' => $item->direct_sku,
                // 'requires_shipping' => '',
                // 'taxable' => '',
                ),
            )
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a bit more information on their wiki:

http://wiki.shopify.com/Product_%28API%29
http://wiki.shopify.com/Product
http://wiki.shopify.com/Product_Variant_(API)

Edit:
Based on [David's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12648799/22417), you should be able to post all product details in one request by including everything in one JSON object.

Comment: Thanks for the links! One of the areas that talks about what I'm partially looking for was http://wiki.shopify.com/Product_%28API%29#Product_properties

Comment: Thanks for the links! One of the areas that talks about what I'm partially looking for was:
http://wiki.shopify.com/Product_%28API%29#Product_properties

I think one of the largest areas I'm still looking for are the default properties for "Modify_a_product".
http://wiki.shopify.com/Product_%28API%29#Modify_a_product

The one thing I'm trying to avoid is making 4 update calls for one products. As I'm seeing it now, worse case senario, I would update: Product, Product Variants, Product Images, Product Metafields. Seems a little to much.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the responses to the GET calls further up the Product doc page (e.g. [this one](http://api.shopify.com/product.html#show)). Everything that is returned there can be edited except for `id`, `created_at`, and `updated_at`.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I did in the end for the "create" product and it has worked well. I'm currently stuck on what is possible when updating a product. It appears that updates can not be performed in the same fashion and I have been updating a single product in 3 or 4 parts. Product, variants, images & metafields. Is that correct?